# What is a fast database equivalent of using reading data from multiple files?

Tags: mysql, database, datastore, flat-file

We have a large amount of data that cannot fit in memory. So we have distributed them in lot of files on disk and we open a file and read records sequentially by moving the pointer ahead. Once the pointer reaches the EOF, we open the next file.

We do the filtering now after loading the data. It would be great if we could run a query to do the filtering like in a database. We want to read all the data from a database instead of files but we cannot bring all the data into memory at one go, how do do we go about this? We can bring the data using chunks but that might take more time over network. Is there a faster alternative to solving this problem? Will using alternative datastorews like Redis or MemSQL help?

Comment: databases are designed for this. there's multi-terabyte databases out there, handled by servers whose ram is only in the gigabyte range... load your data, run the queries, let the DB worry about the ram usage.

Comment: @MarcB You should make that comment into an Answer.

Comment: We were worried that if we fetched more data than what our RAM is, then we might run short of memory.

Comment: You don't have to load everything into memory prior to saving it into the database. You can tell the database to read the data from files, bit by bit. Depending on the structure you might have to prepare it, but that definitely is possible.

Comment: That is okay. Let's assume that the data is loaded into the database. My question is when we fetch records and we happen to fetch more data than what my RAM, what would happen? Ideally, we would need to consume the data as we get it from the database so that our memory usage doesn't go up.

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL's column store is well-designed to solve this kind of problem. It will intelligently compress data and automatically move it between RAM and disk (SSD or HDD) as you query it.

MemSQL will also automatically handle processing files in parallel and distributing the data across nodes.

Here's a quick start guide for MemSQL: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/quick_start/

and some documentation about how to get started with the column store:
http://docs.memsql.com/latest/concepts/columnar/